# need advice on how to host wcf rest service

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, hosting, wcf-rest

I have created a wcf project.  It has some wcf rest services. Now i need to host it to the web server, which is a shared hosting.

My web site is: www.mysite.com.
And the services should have something like: services.mysite.com.
So that when the client call the service, they use something like: http://services.mysite.com/location.svc/location/?id=5

The web config of the wcf project is:

```
<services>
  <service name="MyServices.Location" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyServices.ILocation" behaviorConfiguration="web">
      <identity>
        <dns value="services.mysite.com" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://services.mysite.com/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

I already publish this wcf project to the service.mysite.com. But when I try to access the services, the web browser says "resource cannot be found"

Please give me some idea about what am I doing wrong..

Comment: have you configured your IIS/WebServer to handle .svc requests?

Comment: after trying so many things, I fixed it. I guess, it was something to do with the hosting server.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using .svc file to access the wcf service.
There is tag in .svc file like below :

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="FirstLookOnSilverlight.Web.StudentService" CodeBehind="StudentService.svc.cs" %>
```

If the studentService is in different assembly then where .svc is in.
Then try with full qualified name to reffer the service like

**Service="Namespace.StudentService, assemblyname"**

I have little knowledge about wcf but have face this type of hosting problem.

Comment: The tag in my .svc is "<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MajangoServices.Location" CodeBehind="Location.svc.cs" %>". The Location.svc is in the same assembly.